# Among all checkboxes inside td having specific class only one of them should be checked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a gridview which is rendered in table form as below.In each row i have 12 checkboxes and among them set of 4 checkboxes share the same class. now i want among all checkboxes inside td having specific class only one of them should be checked.class is attached to each td dynamically.for example i want among all tds having class 'gvclass1' only one checkbox can be checked at a time.I want a dynamic variable for class name inside td selector.please help me out..

```
 <div>
        <table runat="server" border="1" width="100%">
        <tr class="row0">
        <td colspan="4" >Aetna commercial</td>
        <td colspan="4">anthem blue cross</td>
        <td colspan="4">anthem healthy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row1">
        <td class="gvclass1">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked="true" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass1">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass1">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass1">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" /></td>
          <td class="gvclass2">
              <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" Checked="true" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass2">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass2">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox7" runat="server" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass2">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox8" runat="server" /></td>
          <td class="gvclass3">
              <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox9" runat="server" Checked="true" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass3">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox10" runat="server" /></td>

         <td class="gvclass3"> <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox11" runat="server" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass3">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox12" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row2">

        <td class="gvclass1">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox13" runat="server" Checked="true" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass1">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox14" runat="server" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass1">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox15" runat="server" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass1">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox16" runat="server" /></td>
          <td class="gvclass2">
              <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox17" runat="server" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass2">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox18" runat="server" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass2">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox19" runat="server" checked="true"/></td>
         <td class="gvclass2">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox20" runat="server" /></td>
          <td class="gvclass3">
              <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox21" runat="server" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass3">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox22" runat="server" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass3">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox23" runat="server" checked="true"/></td>
         <td class="gvclass3">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox24" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: Why you don't use [radio-button's](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)?

Comment: requirement is that I have to use checkboxes

Comment: somebody please help..i am unable to get out of this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make an event listener on all check boxes. Checking what is the parent td class and unchecking all other check boxes with the same td parent class. I am hoping this will help you.

```
jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
var parentClass = jQuery(this).parent('td').attr('class');
var checked = jQuery(this);
jQuery('.'+parentClass+' input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i,e){
    jQuery(this).prop('checked', false);
})
jQuery(checked ).prop('checked', true);
```

})

Comment: I have edited my code.Does anyone knows how can we implement event listener for this code..I want among all tds in a specific row having class 'gvclass1' only one checkbox should be checked and having class 'gvclass2 only one checkbox should be checked.'It should not affect tds in other row..